# Is this a subject-verb agreement mistake in a well-known newspaper?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

> The Guardian: We've built good relationships with people's families, **which really help us** to develop a true sense of person-centred support.

I believe that it should be "**which really helps us**"...because the subject is the idea of "building good relationships with people's families" and this should be treated a singular idea. Let me know whether I am wrong or not.

Comment: The grammar is correct if "which" refers to the relationships (plural), and not to the idea (singular) of building them.

Comment: The phrase _building a good relationships with people's families_ is ungrammatical, and does not appear in the Guardian sentence. It can't be the subject, and you should learn more before trying to correct newspapers.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't have a hobby of correcting newspapers, and I want to understand the grammar in the newspaper because reading them is a good way to learn more English. I always assumed that the verb coming after "which" should be in a singular form.  So I learned something new.  Please don't be so judging person.

Comment: I think the target of ***which*** is inherently ambiguous in the cited context. Only the verb form tells us whether it refers to the (singular) np *[f]act of having built good relations* *(**helps**)*, or (plural) np *good relations* *(**help**)*. So it's entirely a matter of opinion / personal style which verb form is "correct".

Comment: Costa: *the verb coming after "which" should be in a singular form?* Are you seriously suggesting we should never refer to *things **which are** plural?*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica yeah plural is too many and we need to save more for tomorrow. I am just learning English :) Here you are the full story, I got a habit of writing an idea + which + clarification.  So in the beginning I lost a lot of marks because the verb was supposed to be in singular form and after a while I lost one mark because the verb was supposed to in plural form.  This is because I always clarify an idea and usually need to use singular verb.  So I researched for more examples and it was crystal clear, and I found this example which I could not understand .....Thanks :)

Comment: Costa: Ah, right. That's all clear as mud then! :)

Comment: :) I wrote that

Comment: You are right. In very simple terms, where the antecedent of a supplementary relative clause is a clause, the verb in the relative clause is normally singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to read this is to understand the pronoun "which" to stand for "relationships"

> We've built good relationships with people's families, [and these relationships] really help us to develop ...

Therefore there is no error in subject/verb agreement

Answer (score 0):

You are right unless the author meant *which* in the restrictive sense, in other words unless the author intended to convey that the families with whom they've built good relationships are those families that really help...

And that intention strikes me as unlikely.

Comment: That business about a possible restrictive relative clause (we only built relationships with ***those people's families that really help us***, as opposed to ***all*** people's families, or those that *don't* help) doesn't seem relevant. That reading would depend on there ***not being a comma*** before the relative clause, which OP hasn't mentioned.

Comment: Well... given that what's at question is a "well-known newspaper's" mastery of English syntax, I wouldn't think it prudent to simply assume that the newspaper's grip on punctuation is any more trustworthy (or subtle).

Comment: Well, I'm with [John Lawler](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235221/is-this-a-subject-verb-agreement-mistake-in-a-well-known-newspaper/235227?noredirect=1#comment446343_235221) on that one *(nns should learn more before trying to correct newspapers)*. Pragmatically we know perfectly well what's *actually* intended by the cited text. But that's not really the point - it's all about *what the **syntax** "means"*.